# Trying to use app script tied to Google Sheet to write to another user's Sheet/Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

there.

First time poster here. I've been using GAS to build a personal app that takes Telegram input and posts to a Google Sheet. It's a very simple app that helps manage a budget. I'm trying to extend the functionality to allow a couple friends who have expressed interest to post their own transactions to their own Google Sheets hosted on their own Google Accounts.

Right now the only way I can see to do that is to have them "share" their Google Sheet with my user account, which is obviously not preferable. I'd like the app to have authorized access, which would obviously require them to grant the access, but don't want a "shared" sheet.

Is there any way to do this within the Google App Script Editor enviroment? Or do I have to switch everything over to something like Google Cloud? If the latter, can anyone point me toward a tutorial on getting that done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered just giving them the script?

Comment: Yeah, but makes it a really PITA to maintain when I add things. Appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: You can publish your code as an [editor Addon](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons) that the users can install.